# Apache Tomcat 8.5 starting returning 404

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey, tomcat8, tomcat8.5

so I've been building an API using Jersey and Apache Tomcat 8.5, the API was running fine and working and randomly I can only get 404 even when accessing localhost:8080. I'm new to this tech so was wondering if anyone can help.

Here is my web.xml in my API project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>net.codejava</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

When doing this I was messing around with the CORS Policy but even after commenting it out I still get 404. I also had a pop up with something to do with change of source but I just clicked okay. My project is still added to the tomcat server, I've tried cleaning and building, also re-adding the project. There are no errors in my eclipse workspace. I've also been comparing my files to the local history to see if I've just added any typos accidentally but can't find any.

Just to re-iterate I don't believe I've changed any of these files and I've been posting to my server http://localhost:8080/myappname/rest/auth succesfully for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind fixed it now. Somehow the path in my server xml reverted to the previous project name I had. This path attribute changed.

```
  <Context docBase="projectname-api" path="/projectname-backend" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.projectname-api"/></Host>
```